# Quaternion rotation, translation, scale or 4x3/4x4 matrices for Skeletons?

Tags: matrix, quaternion, skeletal-animation

I'm modding a game that uses 4x3 and 4x4 matrices to make skeletons, but I saw that an skeleton can also be made with a quaternian rotation and vector translation and scaling.

What's the difference between both? The first one has more values, I suppose, but, which is better?

If I have a 4x3/4x4 matrices skeleton, can I transform it in some way to the rotation, translation and scaling?

Comment: Hopefully this will explain more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919086/why-are-quaternions-used-for-rotations

Answer (score 1):

Smaller data helps a lot with performance which becomes critical when you have dozens or hundreds of characters with multiple blended animations.

There can also be several advantages to using quaternions when interpolating between frames of an animation. Matrices can theoretically fail to represent certain series of transformations (gimbal lock) and linear interpolation of rotational matrices gives you a slightly incorrect values compared to spherical interpolation of quaternions.

In short, use quaternions and offset vectors. You can reconstruct the final transformation matrix easily enough on the GPU during skinning.

This a gets to be a much longer conversation once animation compression and other high-end techniques are tossed in, but you still typically stick with quaternions.

Comment: I don't think "Matrices can theoretically fail to represent certain series of transformations (gimbal lock)" is true. In what circumstances do they fail?

Comment: Thanks, but is there any form to convert a 4x4 matrix to quaternion rotation, vector translation and vector scaling?

Comment: @Emd4600: it's "matrix decomposition." Here's one explanation of how to decompose a 3D afine transformation matrix into a translation vector, scale vector, and a 3x3 rotation matrix (which can be converted to a quaternion): http://www.gamedev.net/topic/441695-transform-matrix-decomposition/

Comment: The comment about linear interpolation of rotation matrices doing a worse job than quaternion interpolation is very relevant, though (and as previously noted, gimbal lock is specifically a property of Euler angles, not of rotation matrices) - particularly in that it's _much_ tougher to normalize a matrix back to being orthogonal than to normalize a quaternion.

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions are useful for the skeleton representation since animations are often compressed quaternion rotations. So when playing back animations you only need to decompress quaternions for a frame for each joint and multiply the quarernion with the bind pose quaternion of the skeleton. This both preserves memory and is more efficient than using matrices. At the point of rendering though quaternions are often converted to 3x4 matrices and fed to the shader since regular skinning is more efficient with matrices.